# Scala Dataframe columns with space save as a databricks table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am working on databricks notebook (Scala) and I have a spark query that goes kinda like this:

`` df = spark.sql("SELECT columnName AS `Column Name` FROM table") ``

I want to store this as a databricks table. I tried below code for the same:

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("df")
```

But it is giving an error because of the space in the column name. Here's the error:

> Attribute name contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=". Please use alias to rename it.;

I don't want to remove the space so is there any alternative for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's a limitation of the underlying technologies used by Databricks under the hood (for example, [PARQUET-677](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-677)). The only solution here is to rename column, and if you need to have space in the name, do renaming when reading it back.

Comment: In that case, is it possible to store the file as CSV with columns having space?

Comment: yes, it should be possible, but you will lose all performance optimizations when reading data